# Slice the last 4 or otherwise handle this input/output pattern, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, slice

```
print('What is the day and hour (ex., Monday 08AM): ')
appoint = gets.slice[0..-4]
puts(appoint)
```

is returning this error:

/scope.rb:2:in `slice': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
        from /scope.rb:2:in`'

Also tried `slice[appoint.length..-4]` and some other things.

From reading other questions, I gathered that this was how such a slice was done.  I'm not familiar with the regex pattern.  I'd actually like to be able tot return the day of the week, as well, which may mean `from -5 back to input` or `everything up until the space` with some kind of regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this ?

```
appoint = gets.slice(-4,4)
```

For `Monday 08AM` it returns:

```
08AM
```

You can use slice like this: `slice(start, length)`.

In your case `start` is `-4` and `length` is `4`.

**EDIT**
Or with only brackets:

```
appoint = gets[-4..-1]
```

A string is also an array of characters.

Comment: It doesn't work, so I haven't accepted it.  I'm also hoping someone will talk about better ways of handling this string.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: I updated my answer if you want to use brackets instead of `slice` ^^

Answer (score 1):

Regex exmaple:

```
s = "Monday 08AM"

day = /[a-zA-Z]+/
s[day]
=> "Monday"

# \d? to also catch 8AM without 0 at the start
hour = /\d?\d[paPA][mM]/
s[hour]
=> "08AM"
```

[Regex tutorial from Ruby 1.9.3 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)

Comment: Like I think you could just do `/\w/` or `/[[:word:]]/`, right?

Comment: Yes, with your particular string it would work too. I just had in mind that `\w` also covers digits and `[[:word:]]` also covers marks, numbers and connector punctuation, so I wrote it that way without thinking too much about it ;)